# Como adicionar um variavel externa na classe php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, classes, variáveis

Olá pessoal estou criando uma classe para dados de usuário e gostaria de saber como insiro uma variável esterna contendo dados, por exemplo do banco de dados:

```
 class Usuario {

     public $nomecompleto;
}

$DadosUsuaio = new Usuario;
$DadosUsuaio->nomecompleto = $nome_completo;
```

Por exemplo esta variável $nome_completo, nome meu caso quando dou var_dump, dá erro .

poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: A sintaxe parece estar correta. Por quê não edita a pergunta e adiciona a mensagem de erro e o código completo?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: nome_completo in (caminhododiretorio)

Comment: Código completo agora...

Comment: Na verdade é só um teste, esta variavel $nome_completo atribuir meu nome nela de teste "malone moreira de castro" e dei var_dump e deu erro

Comment: Mesmo sendo um teste, o código precisa estar completo. Se você não definiu a variável, obviamente que resultará nesse erro.

Comment: Se eu irei usar para varios usuarios não posso atribuir um valor só né amigo? rs

Comment: a variavel defina dentro da classe? seria isto?

Comment: e como poderia fazer isso usando o PDO

Comment: Se vai atribuir vários, depende de como esses dados chegarão. Como está o banco de dados? Como você recupera esses dados? Como você está iterando sobre eles? Se não fazer uma pergunta clara, não tem como obter uma resposta clara.

Comment: Os dados recuperam através do SELECT no DB usando classe PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sugestão que eu dou é você usar os getters e os setters

Já que você está usando Orientação a Objetos, fica mais fácil:

> class.usuario.php:

```
class usuario {
  private $nome;

  public function getNome(){
    return $this->nome;
  }

  public function setNome($nome){
    $this->nome = $nome;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

No seu class.usuariodao.php recuperando os dados que vem do banco, não esquecendo de usar o require ou include;

```
 $dadosUsuario = new usuario();
 $dadosUsuario->setNome($row['nome']);
```

> E onde vai visualizar a variavel:

```
 $dadosUsuario = new usuario();
 echo $dadosUsuario->getNome();
```

Espero que ajude.

Abraços, Sucesso!

Comment: valeu amigo, eu estou  gostando de usar a função __construct e você gosta muito de usar ela?

Comment: Sim. acho legal!

Comment: blza irmão!!! você é o cara 
Voce tem zap?

Comment: Sim, senhor rsrs.

Comment: passa ai, tem muitos amigos adventistas rs

Comment: manda email pra cbcarlos07@gmail.com, que passo blz?

Comment: a própria IDE gera assim quando é solicitado

Comment: @PapaCharlie pois, comentei e não percebi isso -.-.